# Input numbers must be 6 digit numbers or 9 digits numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make that input numbers are 6 digits or 9 digits numbers. No less than 6 digits, not between 6 and 9 digits and no more than 9 digits numbers. May I know how can I make that? Codes will be insert below

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="badgeid" style="margin-left: -50px;">ID:</label>;
            <div class="col-sm-4">;
            <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="secuid" name="secuid" min="0" placeholder="Enter ID" value=" $return_id">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-6" style="color: red; font-size: 12px; margin-right: 20px;display: contents;">** 6 Digit ST Employee ID / 9 SecurityID **</label>
    </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
```

Below is Javascript.

```
var secuid = document.translot.secuid.value;
    if (secuid == null || secuid == ""){
        alert("Please Insert the ID.")
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: try using `document.translot.secuid.value.length` to get the length of what the user entered.

Comment: @cloned May I know How to do it? I'm basically new to this field that'swhy

Comment: `if (secuid.length != 6 && secuid.length != 9) { alert('Invalid ID length') }` (after your `null` check)

Comment: @Nick https://jsfiddle.net/2s36hf70/1/ Can you please check is this correct?

Comment: @scott hard to say for sure as it's not a complete example. But it seems reasonable

Comment: @scott check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72181980/2813224) no JavaScript needed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is pretty simple - use '**pattern**' alongside **maxlength**.

**Way 1:**

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input pattern attribute</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="secuid">Enter ID:</label>
  <input type="text" id="secuid" name="secuid" pattern="(\d{6}|\d{9})" maxlength="9" title="Enter ID"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**See JSFiddle (1)** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nehu3L0q/1/)

**Way 2**
use minlength=6, maxlength=9, and allow for only numbers: pattern="[0-9]+

```
<input type="text" id="secuid" name="secuid" pattern="[0-9]+" minlength="6" maxlength="9" title="Enter ID">
```

**See JSFiddle (2)**  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0fx1wo65/)

**Note:**  no javascript needed

Comment: You could've at least changed the regex so it doesn't look exactly like my answer posted an hour before yours. 

Comment: That regex is totally wrong, I'd do some serious research in what you "claim" you have actual knowledge in and test your answer because it allows anything in.

Comment: The 2nd example will also accept 7 and 8 digit numbers, you have yet to have an answer that's different than [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72181980/2813224)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `pattern` attribute and this regex:

```js
\b\d{6}\b|\b\d{9}\b
/* Start with a non-word character then 6 consecutive digits then 
another non-word character OR start with a non-word character then 
9 consecutive digits then another non-word character */
```

`type="number"` ignores `pattern` attribute believe it or not, so use `type="tel"`

In the example test it by observing the warning messages it gives as will as the invalid error message when attempting to send anything not within the criteria.

```html
<form>
<input type='tel' pattern='\b\d{6}\b|\b\d{9}\b' required>
<button>TEST</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ` <input type="number" pattern='\b\d{6}\b|\b\d{9}\b' required class="form-control" id="secuid" name="secuid" min="0" placeholder="Enter ID" value=" $return_id"> `  U mean like this?

Comment: `pattern` will not work with `type="number"` you need to use `type="tel"` and remove `min="0"` everything else is ok. Also, `required` won't work unless the `<input>` is in a `<form>`.

Comment: Sure no problem. I think You're confused by the guy that [copied my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182971/2813224) and accepted his post instead of mine.